# AutoField not working in Django-nonrel

Tags: django, django-nonrel

Model:

```
class MasterDishList(models.Model):
    dishid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    dishname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    dishprice = models.IntegerField()
```

And if I try:

```
objectoadd = MasterDishList.objects.create(dishname="somename", dishprice=100, username=userobject)
```

I get:

```
/home/abd/Development/Projects/misc/fadster-backend/djangotoolbox/db/basecompiler.pyc in execute_sql(self, return_id)
    581                 if value is None and not field.null and not field.primary_key:
    582                     raise IntegrityError("You can't set %s (a non-nullable "
--> 583                                          "field) to None!" % field.name)
    584 
    585                 # Prepare value for database, note that query.values have

IntegrityError: You can't set dishid (a non-nullable field) to None!
```

This is clearly a bug right? Or am I missing something?
Any workaround for this that I can possibly use?

Comment: Django automatically adds a primary key to each model. Why do you need to add it by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key seems to be the same as the default. It's recommended to not specify the field as it will automatically be added by django:

[Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

You can just leave your model as:

```
class MasterDishList(models.Model):
    dishname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.ForeignKey(User)
    dishprice = models.IntegerField()
```